# how to send image from jsp to server dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dynamic-data

In my application I want to create some image in my HTML elements and send it to my server (not the URL of that image). How can I achieve this? Is there any way to do this by using Javascript or AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

This [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) pretty much anserws you question, after you take the image data you can send it to your server with 
Ajax.

For instance in jQuery you would write

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://your_server.com/process_image',
    data: image_data
 });
```

then from server side read raw post data and decode data with base64.